# Entity RemoveRange delete all rows

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My Table:

SomeID | AnotherID

**I want to delete all rows by SomeID**

```
db.MyTable.RemoveRange(db.MyTable.Where(x => x.SomeID == u.SomeID));
```

But when I call SaveChanges() all rows are deleted.

Entity Framework 6

**Edit 1**

SQL Profiles shows that the entity is trying to remove the rows by the column "B" (AnotherID) the correct is delete by column "A" (SomeID). What is wrong?

**Edit 2**

My entity model:

```
this.HasKey(t => t.SomeID).
Property(x => x.SomeID).
HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

this.HasKey(t => t.AnotherID).
Property(x => x.AnotherID).
HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

I think entity framework is trying to delete by "PK", maybe my entity model is wrong?

Comment: where are you getting `u.SomeID` from?

Comment: @Alberto whats problem with this

Comment: For me it looks like u has the same Ids as x

Comment: I am guessing maybe you have a mis-type in the actual code that you are not showing like `Where(x => x.SomeID == x.SomeID)` (note the 2 `x` references) or you never had any records that had a `SomeId` value other than just the one you are removing.

Comment: Break it into 2 steps and debug.

Comment: var temp = db.MyTable.Where(x => x.SomeID == tempSomeID). temp has just one item, exact the item i want to delete. But if I call db.MyTable.RemoveRange(temp) all the 6 rows are deleted.

Comment: Sounds like a complete mess. What does the ChangeTracker say about the before/after state for each item?

Comment: Also, can you reproduce this with a fresh schema what's just containing these two columns, or are you hiding some complexity in your question? Regarding the "delete by...": no matter how you enumerate the entries, EF will probably try to delete them by PK, so if your model ID is not accurately reflecting you database PK, you are in for some trouble.

Comment: Do you get the other 5 records if you run `var tempNoDelete = db.MyTable.Where(x => x.SomeID != tempSomeID);` ?

Comment: SomeID and AnotherID are a composit PK.

Comment: That's not how you declare a composite PK. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617(v=vs.113).aspx)